# What do the different options for subtype enumerator in StringProperty do?

Tags: python

[`bpy.props.StringProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) has `[‘FILE_PATH’, ‘DIR_PATH’, ‘FILE_NAME’, ‘BYTE_STRING’, ‘PASSWORD’, ‘NONE’]` as options, but nowhere are those documented.

It seams simple enough to guess what FILE_PATH, DIR_PATH, and FILE_NAME do, but what do they all do?
Are these actually documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

**[`bpy.props.StringProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty)`.subtype`**

> **FILE_PATH**
>
> Use for storing file paths. Adds a button to the UI property markup, that when used sets the string
>   to the file path chosen. Option to make it a relative path.
>
> **DIR_PATH**
>
> Use for storing directory paths. Adds a button to the UI property markup, that when used sets the string
>   to the directory path chosen.
>
> **FILE_NAME**
>
> AFAICT is for, as the name suggests storing a filename.  Filenames cannot
>   contain certain characters. It doesn't appear to in anyway auto-parse.
>   The Paint Palettes addon uses the subtype for preset file names. The
>   following method is used to parse out illegal / invalid chars.
>
> ```
> def as_filename(name):  # could reuse for other presets
>     for char in " !@#$%^&*(){}:\";'[]<>,.\\/?":
>         name = name.replace(char, '_')
>     return name.lower().strip()
> ```
>
> **BYTE_STRING**
>
> Stores the string as a utf-8 encoded byte string.  Equivalent of
>   `"string".encode()`.
>
> **PASSWORD**
>
> Displays asterisks (*) when input is typed in the UI. Stores the string as entered.
>
> **NONE**
>
> Default. None of the above.

**Run a script and see.**

Like any code we can run and see, the worst thing that can happen is your computer explodes, starts a fire an burns down your city.

Here is a test script to set a string property of each subtype to the window manager, and display them in a panel (using the simple panel template code) as well as write their value to system console on change.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty

subtypes = ['FILE_PATH', 'DIR_PATH', 'FILE_NAME', 'BYTE_STRING', 'PASSWORD', 'NONE']

def print_value(subtype):
    def print_value(self, context):
        print(subtype, getattr(self, subtype))
    return print_value

for st in subtypes:
    setattr(bpy.types.WindowManager,
            st, 
            StringProperty(subtype=st, update=print_value(st)))


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        layout = self.layout
        for st in subtypes:
            layout.prop(wm, st)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Here is the result.

[image]

and the result of setting all to "xxxxxx" in the panel written to system console.

```
FILE_PATH xxxxxx
DIR_PATH xxxxxx
FILE_NAME xxxxxx
BYTE_STRING b'xxxxxx'
PASSWORD xxxxxx
NONE xxxxxx
```